# Multiple Goals with Bayesian A/B Testing

Tags: bayesian, ab-test

I am transitioning my team from frequentist to Bayesian A/B testing and have spent a lot of time researching all the possible questions and concerns that people may have.  The one critical question that I cannot seem to find a satisfactory answer to is how to deal with multiple goals.  For example, let's say we want to learn about the impact of a new design on both clicks to Facebook and purchases - two somewhat unrelated goals.

I know this is possible as I see on VWO (who use a Bayesian framework) that they allow up to 5 goals but I don't feel confident about whether I need to make any sort of adjustments like I would with a Frequentist approach. The closest I've been able to find is the quote below but I'm not sure how to translate this into practice. For those of you who do Bayesian A/B testing, do you make any adjustments when analyzing multiple goals?  Perhaps being more strict with the threshold of caring? Or is this a non-issue due to the Bayesian assumptions / construct?

> Bayesian analysis does not base decisions on error control. Indeed, Bayesian analysis does not use sampling distributions. [...] Instead of using error rates, Bayesian decisions are based on properties of the posterior distribution on parameter values.  Of course, ignoring errors rates does not make them go away. Any decision rule on noisy data will eventually commit an error on some set of data, because ultimately the errors come from noise that spawns random coincidences of rogue data. - Kruschke & Liddell (https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13423-016-1221-4)

Comment: I can never read about A/B testing without thinking of this: http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=132

Comment: Thanks - I've looked into multi-armed bandit and I think they only work for certain types of tests - they don't allow the same type of results as an evenly split randomized experiment.